# Deinstalling OpenCL under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencl

I am writing a short tutorial about OpenCL under Ubuntu with the NVIDIA SDK, so I think a short passage about`How to get rid of it?!` would be appropriate.

So would it be sufficient

1. to change the driver to a 'standard' driver via the `Menu -> System Preferences -> Additional Driver` and
2. to delete the folder with the SDK, aka `$(HOME)/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK`?

Would you recommend deleting all the OpenCL files in `/usr/lib(32)` and `user/local` as well? Is there something, which I have overlooked?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Getting Started Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0_rc2/docs/Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) (PDF; for Linux) explains that you can uninstall the SDK by just deleting the directory.

Note that the "standard" NVIDIA driver also comes with CUDA and OpenCL libraries. I would not delete these manually when attempting to de-install a development version of the driver. As far as I know, when you install an NVIDIA driver, it will automatically de-install older / other versions of the driver; you shouldn't need to do anything manually.